# A very simple T-SQL statement syntax error

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I'm just trying to query if any table exist in my database by the following statement:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM db_name.sys.tables WHERE name = 'table_name')
```

I get a syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

What is wrong? How to check if a table exists in my database.

Comment: Sorry new to SQL. What do you mean by THEN? Can you please give full syntax to query table any if any table exit or not

Comment: @StuartLC `THEN` is for `CASE`. T-SQL's if syntax is `IF <condition> [BEGIN...END][ELSE][BEGIN...END]`.

Comment: @masiboo We need some wider context. the code you posted is fine.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I mean OP isn't doing anything in the event of a match

Comment: @StuartLC Yes, your answer covers it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [IF condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql) in SQL needs a statement or block to be executed if the condition matches (i.e. the "then" statement or block), and optionally an "else" statement / block can be added, like so:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mydbname.sys.tables WHERE name = 'MyTable')
    PRINT 'FOUND';
ELSE
    PRINT 'NOT FOUND';
```

If you need to execute multiple statements in either 'then' or 'else', then wrap them in a block delimited with BEGIN / END.

Note if you are from a FP background, the `IF` statement is the old school side-effecting branch style, not the conditional / pattern match style, i.e. you can't do this

```
DECLARE @isFound BIT;
SET @isFound = IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM mydbname.sys.tables WHERE name ='MyTable')
-- ** syntax error
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose some output to check if the table exists. For example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1') Select 1 ELSE Select 0
```

This will return `0` or `1` if `table1` exists or not.

Other way:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1')
```

Whcih will return `1` if `table1` exists, or no record otherwise.

**Note:** You can also omit the `EXISTS` and use something like this:

```
SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table1'
```

which will return `1` or no record based on existence of `table1`.